Kernel Panic: "VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)"
I can't ssh to my server this night, so I connected to the virtual monitor and found this error.
VFS: Cannot open root device "UUID=f24b5d1f-7c0f-4a53-ad16-b1dee9b894d7" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

What I Have Tried:

Tried booting from older images, but I failed with the same error.
Checked UUID in GRUB shell and found the UUID is the same as boot config. Currently, I can't plugin a live system usb into this server remotely, so I asked chatgpt is there a way to check uuid of a disk without booting. It said I can check with the ls command in grub shell. There I found the UUID is the same as the booting config trying to boot from. I can also view some files using the ls command in GRUB shell. I am not sure ifgpt is giving me the right answer, but that's what I have done.

Partition hd0,msdos1: Filesystem type ext* - Label '' - UUID f24b5d1f-7c0f-4a53-ad16-b1dee9b894d7

Error is:
VFS: Cannot open root device "UUID=f24b5d1f-7c0f-4a53-ad16-b1dee9b894d7"

The UUID looks correct to me.
Question:
What kind of problem is my computer facing at? Is it a disk failure or invalid kernel boot config error? Sorry I don't know much about the kernel and boot configuration.
I'd like to try this method if I'm allowed to plug in a live USB: Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
